# Extract values from JSON Decode

Tags: json

var jsonObject = [{"location":{"value":{"display_value":"Columbia","sys_id":"3ff96113133ad20064eeb027d144b025"}},"access_level":{"value":"[{\"display_value\":\"Extended Access\",\"sys_id\":\"bb6f038a134b5e00958db168d144b022\"},{\"display_value\":\"Remote/Traveling\",\"sys_id\":\"3f6f038a134b5e00958db168d144b022\"}]"}},{"location":{"value":{"display_value":"Health","sys_id":"bff96113133ad20064eeb027d144b025"}},"access_level":{"value":"[{\"display_value\":\"GA Extended Access\",\"sys_id\":\"bf6f038a134b5e00958db168d144b022\"},{\"display_value\":\"Technician\",\"sys_id\":\"f28f038a134b5e00958db168d144b0b0\"}]"}},{"location":{"value":{"display_value":"Commerce","sys_id":"b3f96113133ad20064eeb027d144b026"}},"access_level":{"value":"[{\"display_value\":\"Management\",\"sys_id\":\"4278471d4f935a40ccb8188af110c7e9\"},{\"display_value\":\"Remote/Traveling\",\"sys_id\":\"376f038a134b5e00958db168d144b023\"},{\"display_value\":\"Employee\",\"sys_id\":\"781dfa954f135a40ccb8188af110c713\"}]"}}]

**From the above JSON, I am trying to get display_value from access_level but getting result as undefined**

```
var obj = new JSON().decode(jsonObject);

obj[0].location.value.display_value --> Columbia (result) 
obj[0].access_level.value --> [{\"display_value\":\"Extended Access\",\"sys_id\":\"bb6f038a134b5e00958db168d144b022\"},{\"display_value\":\"Remote/Traveling\",\"sys_id\":\"3f6f038a134b5e00958db168d144b022\"}]
obj[0].access_level.value[0] --> [
**obj[0].access_level.value.display_value  --> undefined**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have to parse the content of obj[0].access_level it seems to be a string, so you cannot access as you are trying.

you can do: JSON.parse(obj[0].access_level.value)

[image]

evaluating `obj[0].access_level.value` and evaluating `JSON.parse(obj[0].access_level.value)`

[image]

then you could run `JSON.parse(obj[0].access_level.value)[0].display_value`

Comment: Ya, value inside is string. Is there any way to access it? @JPRLCol